# PHP Time Conversion and Timezones

Tags: php, date, timezone

I'm trying to convert an RSS date (ISO 8601) to an iCalendar date. I thought I would turn the initial date time to a Unix timestamp, then format it with `strftime`.

I understand that `strftime` changes a date time to local time.

I am fetching the initial `$date` value from a Wordpress RSS feed, configured to the Europe/Zurich timezone. The date fetched from RSS is correct (starting on Nov. 15th at 8am).

When I convert it, it gets an extra hour.

I had to set `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` in order to keep the time unchanged.

```
$tz = "Europe/Zurich";
//date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); //not Europe/Zurich
$date = "2019-11-15T08:00:00+00:00";
$dt = strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", strtotime($date));

echo $date . "\r\n";
echo strtotime($date) . "\r\n";
echo $dt . "\r\n";
```

- 2019-11-15T08:00:00+00:00
- 20191115T090000

I get real confused working with timezones...
The initial value is 8am in Zurich, but when transposed to the iCalendar date, even though the timezone is the same, it gets added that one hour.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the more modern `DateTime` class when working with dates:

```
$date = "2019-11-15T08:00:00+00:00";
$dtobj = new \DateTime($date);

var_dump($dtobj);
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo "\n";
echo $dtobj->format("Ymd\This");
```

On my system, this results in:

```
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "2019-11-15 08:00:00.000000"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(1)
  public $timezone =>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
America/Toronto
20191115T080000
```

As you can see, the object stores the timezone as a property, so the timezone on the system is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

- The `$tz` variable has no meaning as does absolutely nothing for the conversion.
- `strtotime` takes the timezone either from the string itself if it contains timezone information, or from `date_default_timezone_set` if the string contains no timezone information. Your string *does* contain timezone information.
- `strftime` uses the timezone set in the system's **`TZ` environment variable**. That is *not* `$tz`, it's set by your operating system "outside" of PHP.

So, the string is parsed as UTC timestamp because it contains a `+00:00` timezone, and is then converted to whatever your local `TZ` is.

If you want a PHP date formatting function that obeys `date_default_timezone_set` instead of the more obscure `TZ`, that would be [`date`](https://php.net/date).

Comment: Sorry, $tz was a leftover of me trying to set timezones with DateTime...